# data frame in which elements are not single columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I've been using R for a long time, so I can't say "hi, I'm a novice, explain this to me".  But that's what I'd like to ask because I've run into this problem now and then and every time I don't solve it and work on something else.  But today I'm curious enough to ask.

I think of a data frame as a collection of columns, each of the same length.  I am aware that is wrong, however. It is wrong because into a data frame one can insert matrices, multi-column elements. When I accidentally do that, I end up with a thing that does not print true to the screen. There are

1. Seemingly inconsistent column names between what R "head" says it has and what it really has, and
2. I can't find a definite way to ask a data frame "are you a regular, one column per variable data frames," or "do you have some of those frustrating internal structures that makes life difficult"?

You can see what I mean if you do this. Run

```
 example(predict.lm)
```

That runs the predict method and it generates a matrix of output named pt.

Then change the last step of their example, instead of taking the matrix output as free standing, add it to the data frame named npk

```
npk$predict <- predict(npk.aov, type = "terms")
```

After that, what is npk?  Is it still a data frame? Yes

```
> is.data.frame(npk)
  [1] TRUE
```

Hmm, note how head reports the column names:

```
> head(npk)
  block N P K yield predict.block  predict.N  predict.P
1     1 0 1 1  49.5    -0.8500000 -4.9250000  0.2083333
2     1 1 1 0  62.8    -0.8500000  4.9250000  0.2083333
3     1 0 0 0  46.8    -0.8500000 -4.9250000 -0.2083333
4     1 1 0 1  57.0    -0.8500000  4.9250000 -0.2083333
5     2 1 0 0  59.8     2.5750000  4.9250000 -0.2083333
6     2 1 1 1  58.5     2.5750000  4.9250000  0.2083333
 predict.K predict.N:P predict.N:K predict.P:K
1 -0.9583333   0.9416667   1.1750000   0.4250000
2  0.9583333  -2.8250000   1.1750000  -0.1416667
3  0.9583333   0.9416667   1.1750000  -0.1416667
4 -0.9583333   0.9416667  -3.5250000  -0.1416667
5  0.9583333   0.9416667   1.1750000  -0.1416667
6 -0.9583333  -2.8250000  -3.5250000   0.4250000
  predict.N:P:K
1     0.0000000
2     0.0000000
3     0.0000000
4     0.0000000
5     0.0000000
6     0.0000000
```

This makes it appear as though there are columns named "predict.block" or "predict.P", but there are not:

```
> colnames(npk)
[1] "block"   "N"       "P"       "K"       "yield"  
[6] "predict"
```

The function "colnames" would be more appropriately named "column_or_whatever_else_we_find_here".

And you get nothing trying

```
> npk$predict.P
NULL
```

To access those "columns" inside predict, you have to know the structure and ask in the matrix way:

```
> npk$predict[ , "P"] 
         1          2          3          4          5 
 0.2083333  0.2083333 -0.2083333 -0.2083333 -0.2083333  
         6          7          8          9         10 
 0.2083333 -0.2083333  0.2083333  0.2083333  0.2083333 
        11         12         13         14         15 
-0.2083333 -0.2083333 -0.2083333  0.2083333 -0.2083333 
        16         17         18         19         20 
 0.2083333  0.2083333 -0.2083333 -0.2083333  0.2083333 
        21         22         23         24 
-0.2083333  0.2083333  0.2083333 -0.2083333
```

I just picked this example to show the thing that often accidentally happens to me and students when they append non-column things to data frames.

The correct way to join npk and the predict output is merge, I understand that too

```
> npk.new <- merge(npk, pt, by = "row.names", 
                   suffixes = c("", ".predict"))
> colnames(npk.new)
 [1] "Row.names"     "block"         "N"            
 [4] "P"             "K"             "yield"        
 [7] "block.predict" "N.predict"     "P.predict"    
 [10] "K.predict"     "N:P"           "N:K"          
 [13] "P:K"           "N:P:K"
```

However, as life goes, sometimes we get a matrix back from a function when we are thinking there is a single column and we accidentally end up with that "matrix inside a data frame" kind of structure.

Mostly I want to ask "do you notice this too and does it frustrate you the way it frustrates me?" but I know that is not constructive. Here are more constructive things to ask.

If you are given a data frame, what is the most direct route to know if all of the "columns" in it are singular columns.  I've tried the obvious like:

```
> sapply(npk, is.atomic)
  block       N       P       K   yield predict 
  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE 
> sapply(npk, is.vector)
  block       N       P       K   yield predict 
  FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE
```

So far, I know I can ask an element in a data frame if it is a matrix

```
> sapply(npk, is.matrix)
  block       N       P       K   yield predict 
  FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE
```

Hence I could write a function that asks each column "are you a matrix" are you a "data frame", are you an "array".  But it seems, well, too tedious.

Comment: How about looking at the autocomplete of npk$ to see if it features you anything other than usual column names? In RStudio you just have to skim the icons.

Comment: `str` is your friend, e.g., `str(npk)`.

Comment: Also,, I think *"head reports the column names"* is a poor way to describe `head`. What `head` does is return (and print) the first 6 rows. `names()` or `colnames()` returns the column names - and there is a single column named `"predict"`, it just happens to be a column of matrices.

Answer (score 4):

You could maybe define

```
is.simple <- function(x) {is.vector(x) | is.factor(x)}

sapply(npk, is.simple)
```

or maybe

```
no.dims <- function(x) {is.null(dim(x))}
sapply(npk, no.dims)
```

depending on what exactly you were looking for.

It would be safer to add columns to `npk` with

```
npk <- cbind(npk, predict = predict(npk.aov, type = "terms"))
```

if you are unsure of the data types involved. A direct assignment is more dangerous.

Comment: I've tested is.simple() on a few examples and did not fail yet.

Comment: Well, to burst my own bubble, it will fail with `sapply(data.frame(x=as.Date("2001-01-01")), is.simple)`. But the `no.dims` will be fine. Dates have extra attributes like factors.

Comment: Ach. I noticed Date problem just now and logged in to mention it.  You beat me to it.  The more I look into this, the more puzzled I am that R allows the insertion of non-single-columns into data frames. IMHO, it should not be defined as a data frame anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I. Using `class` inside `sapply()`

```
   npk$predict <- predict(npk.aov, type = "terms")
   sapply(npk,class)
   #     block         N         P         K     yield   predict 
   #  "factor"  "factor"  "factor"  "factor" "numeric"  "matrix"
```

II. Using `dim` inside `sapply()`

```
   sapply(npk,dim)
   # $block
   # NULL

   # $N
   # NULL

   # $P
   # NULL

   # $K
   # NULL

   # $yield
   # NULL

   # $predict
   # [1] 24  8
```

III. Using `colnames`inside `sapply()`

```
   sapply(npk,colnames)
   # $block
   # NULL

   # $N
   # NULL

   # $P
   # NULL

   # $K
   # NULL

   # $yield
   # NULL

   # $predict
   # [1] "block" "N"     "P"     "K"     "N:P"   "N:K"   "P:K"   "N:P:K"
```

IV. Using `attributes` inside `sapply()`

```
   sapply(npk,attributes)
   # $block
   # $block$levels
   # [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6"

   # $block$class
   # [1] "factor"


   # $N
   # $N$levels
   # [1] "0" "1"

   # $N$class
   # [1] "factor"


   # $P
   # $P$levels
   # [1] "0" "1"

   # $P$class
   # [1] "factor"


   # $K
   # $K$levels
   # [1] "0" "1"

   # $K$class
   # [1] "factor"


   # $yield
   # NULL

   # $predict
   # $predict$dim
   # [1] 24  8

   # $predict$dimnames
   # $predict$dimnames[[1]]
   #  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13"  "14" "15"
   # [16] "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24"

   # $predict$dimnames[[2]]
   # [1] "block" "N"     "P"     "K"     "N:P"   "N:K"   "P:K"   "N:P:K"


   # $predict$constant
   # [1] 54.875
```

V. About `npk`

```
   class(npk)
   # [1] "data.frame"

   mode(npk)
   # [1] "list"

   typeof(npk)
   # [1] "list"

   attributes(npk)
   # $names
   # [1] "block"   "N"       "P"       "K"       "yield"   "predict"

   # $row.names
   #  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24

   # $class
   # [1] "data.frame"


   str(npk)
   # 'data.frame':   24 obs. of  6 variables:
   #  $ block  : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3  ...
   #  $ N      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
   #  $ P      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
   #  $ K      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 ...
   #  $ yield  : num  49.5 62.8 46.8 57 59.8 58.5 55.5 56 62.8 55.8 ...
   #  $ predict: num [1:24, 1:8] -0.85 -0.85 -0.85 -0.85 2.57 ...
   #  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
   #   .. ..$ : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
   #   .. ..$ : chr  "block" "N" "P" "K" ...
   #   ..- attr(*, "constant")= num 54.9


   dim(npk)
   # [1] 24  6

   dimnames(npk)
   # [[1]]
   #  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"
   # [16] "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24"

   # [[2]]
   # [1] "block"   "N"       "P"       "K"       "yield"   "predict"


  summary.default(npk)
  #         Length    Class    Mode   
  #  block      24    factor numeric
  #  N          24    factor numeric
  #  P          24    factor numeric
  #  K          24    factor numeric
  #  yield      24    -none- numeric
  #  predict   192    -none- numeric
```

VI. Extra Information: Install and load `psych` package

```
  library(psych)
  list(npk_1_5 = describe(npk[,-6]),npk_6 = describe(npk[,6]))
  $npk_1_5
  #        vars  n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad  min  max range skew kurtosis   se
  # block*    1 24  3.50 1.74   3.50    3.50 2.22  1.0  6.0   5.0 0.00    -1.41 0.36
  # N*        2 24  1.50 0.51   1.50    1.50 0.74  1.0  2.0   1.0 0.00    -2.08 0.10
  # P*        3 24  1.50 0.51   1.50    1.50 0.74  1.0  2.0   1.0 0.00    -2.08 0.10
  # K*        4 24  1.50 0.51   1.50    1.50 0.74  1.0  2.0   1.0 0.00    -2.08 0.10
  # yield     5 24 54.88 6.17  55.65   54.75 6.15 44.2 69.5  25.3 0.24    -0.51 1.26

  # $npk_6
  #       vars  n mean   sd median trimmed  mad   min  max range  skew kurtosis   se
  # block    1 24    0 3.86   0.31   -0.11 5.13 -4.75 5.90 10.65  0.10    -1.41 0.79
  # N        2 24    0 5.03   0.00    0.00 7.30 -4.92 4.92  9.85  0.00    -2.08 1.03
  # P        3 24    0 0.21   0.00    0.00 0.31 -0.21 0.21  0.42  0.00    -2.08 0.04
  # K        4 24    0 0.98   0.00    0.00 1.42 -0.96 0.96  1.92  0.00    -2.08 0.20
  # N:P      5 24    0 1.67   0.94    0.19 0.00 -2.82 0.94  3.77 -1.08    -0.86 0.34
  # N:K      6 24    0 2.08   1.17    0.23 0.00 -3.52 1.17  4.70 -1.08    -0.86 0.42
  # P:K      7 24    0 0.25  -0.14   -0.03 0.00 -0.14 0.43  0.57  1.08    -0.86 0.05
  # N:P:K    8 24    0 0.00   0.00    0.00 0.00  0.00 0.00  0.00   NaN      NaN 0.00
```